# Android ArrayList Shuffle

Tags: android

I have a ArrayList> I store my questioners here from PHP
It look like {{question, optA, optB, optC, optD, answer},{question, optA, optB, optC, optD, answer}, .....}}

How do i shuffle only my A,B,C,D like D,B,A,C? {question, optD, optB, optA, optC, answer}

Im using this code

```
//myArray
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getQuestion = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> choices;


        //first retrive elements from getQuestionArray
        questIndex = getQuestion.get(arrayRow).get(0);
        aIndex = getQuestion.get(arrayRow).get(1);
        bIndex = getQuestion.get(arrayRow).get(2);
        cIndex = getQuestion.get(arrayRow).get(3);
        dIndex = getQuestion.get(arrayRow).get(4);
        answerIndex = getQuestion.get(arrayRow).get(5);


        //get the correct answer (This is Word of senteces)
        String correctAnswer = "";
        if(answerIndex.equals("a")){
            correctAnswer = aIndex;
        }else if(answerIndex.equals("b")){
            correctAnswer = bIndex;
        }else if(answerIndex.equals("c")){
            correctAnswer = cIndex;
        }else if(answerIndex.equals("d")){
            correctAnswer = dIndex;
        }

        //Im using this to shuffle my abcd Im creating new ArrayList for that
        choices.add(aIndex);
        choices.add(bIndex);
        choices.add(cIndex);
        choices.add(dIndex);

        Collections.shuffle(choices);

        int correctIndex;
        //Find now where is our correct answer
        correctIndex = choices.indexOf(correctAnswer);


        //our correct letter now
        switch(correctIndex){
        case 0:
            answerIndex = "a";
            break;
        case 1:
            answerIndex = "b";
            break;
        case 2:
            answerIndex = "c";
            break;
        case 3:
            answerIndex = "d";
            break;
        }

        aIndex = choices.get(0);
        bIndex = choices.get(1);
        cIndex = choices.get(2);
        dIndex = choices.get(3);

        question.setText(questIndex);
        cA.setText(aIndex);
        cB.setText(bIndex);
        cC.setText(cIndex);
        cD.setText(dIndex);
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Should´t you initialize your choices ArrayList?

Comment: What is wrong with your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class MyQuestion with this fields:

```
public class MyQuestion{
    String question;
    String answer;
    List<String> options;
}
```

and then call Collections.shuffle(options);

Or you create a method like this:

```
 public static void shuffle(List list, int a, int b){
        List shuffleList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
           shuffleList.add(list.get(i));
        Collections.shuffle(shuffleList);
        for (int i = a; i i<= b; i++)
            list.set(i, shuffleList.get(i-a));
    }
```

I didn't use generics just to be faster, but it's easy to add them